# How to find similar trajectories

Tags: postgresql, gis

I am very new in GIS. I am using an existing data set which is a collection of triplets along with its trajectory ID. I need to find similar trajectories. I am using postgres as database. I have imported the data set  and I want to visualize the trajectories.How can I convert the existing data in linestring?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just need a LineString for each trajectory ID (meaning that by 'finding similar trajectories')? If so, you want to use [ST_MakeLine](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) (spatial aggregate version) in conjunction with [ST_MakePoint](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html). For PostGIS 9.0 and higher you could do something like:

```
SELECT points.trackid,
       ST_MakeLine(points.point_geom ORDER BY points.timedetails) AS line_geom
FROM (SELECT data.trackid,
             data.timedetails,
             ST_MakePoint(data.longitude, data.latitude) AS point_geom
      FROM your_table AS data) AS points
GROUP BY points.trackid;
```

Comment: Yes I  did this already. But now I want to compare those trajectories. Can I use LCSS algorithm for this? What would be the best algorithm for finding similar trajectories?

Comment: I thought so, that was easy to figure out...,) There is the [Pg-trajectory](http://pg-trajectory.dmlab.cs.gsu.edu/) extension for PostGIS that is under recent developement and seems to aim at handling the LCSS problem. Extensions are easy to use and that might be what you are looking for. I don´t know much about comparing spatiotemporal data, though...